# how big a json/xml response is alright

Tags: java, ajax, sharepoint

Say, I retrieve a xml/json response which contains almost 1000 items.what would be the impact on processing it? leaving pagination aside, I would also need to attach event handlers to most of the items in the response.

Is it practical in the sense that client side javascript can handle this much processing? will it cause the script to hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is the cost of "processing" one item.

If all you want to do is generate some HTML based on each *JSON* item and append it to the *DOM*, then it is fast enough on modern browsers.

This simple test can show you how fast it would feel like:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y4EE/

```
var data = [];

for(i = 0; i<1000; ++i) {
    data[i] = {
        key1: i,
        key2: i,
        key3: i
    };
}

var html = "";

$.each(data, function(indexInArray, value){
    html += '<li class="item">';
    html += value.key1 + ', ' + value.key2 + ', ' + value.key3;
    html += '</li>';
});

$('#container').append(html);
```

About the events part, if you add event handlers for **each** item added, than that is impractical. This will slow your browser a lot.
Instead, use event delegation. You add only one event to the parent of the items and then delegate the event to the right child item. *jQuery* has nice support for this and it is not the only one.